# Continue Page Numbers in Appendix

Tags: page-numbering, appendices

I am writing a thesis using LaTex and I was told that my numbering cannot restart in the Appendices, which seems wrong to me but I'm not going to argue it.  I am using the report class and the appendix command.  It seems that the appendix command restarts the numbering when it is used.  However, I would like to use the appendix command but not reset my page numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage {fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx, amssymb, changepage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pgnumchapter_nums}
\usepackage{titlepg}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{appendix}

%              this is for the list of symbols page, if desired
\def\listofsymbols{\input{symbols} \clearpage}
\def\addsymbol #1: #2#3{$#1$\> \parbox{5in}{#2 \dotfill  \pageref{#3}}\\}
\def\newnot#1{\label{#1}}
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
% \fancyhead[LE,RO]{helv \thepage}
\fancyhead[L,R]{helv \thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}     %%test this

%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage\hspace{2em}\footnotesize{\leftmark}}  % try this to move over header

\addtolength{\voffset}{-4em}                                % May2009 added this to move page number up a bit


\doublespacing

\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 pt}          %this prints a line under the header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0  pt}         %this prints a line under the footer


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\normalsize{Table of Contents}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\normalsize{List of Figures}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\normalsize{List of Tables}}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\normalsize{Bibliography}}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{\normalsize{Index}}



\pdfpagewidth 8.5in
\pdfpageheight 11in 

\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5in}  
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5in} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.in}    
\setlength{\headheight}{0.5in}
\setlength{\headwidth}{6.0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.65in}                                 
\setlength{\parindent}{12mm}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%
%%%  This begins the frontmatter of the document, everything preceding the body 
%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\thesistitlepage

\thesiscopyrightpage              

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}                                % added May2009
\thesisabstract




\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}                 % added May2009
\thesisacknowledgments

\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000} \makeatother


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\normalsize{Table of Contents}}      % added this line May2010 to fix issue with 
\tableofcontents                                                 %toc appearing in too large a font size when used in Linux




\newpage        % added June 2009


\newpage     % added June2009
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}                     % added May2009
\listoffigures



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%
%%%  This begins the body of the document
%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\include{chapter1}

\include{chapter2}

\include{chapter3}

\include{chapter4}

\include{chapter5}

\include{chapter6}

\addappheadtotoc
\include{chapter7}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\appendix
%\appendixpage
\renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}
\include{appendixA}

\include{AppendixB}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}        % added May2009
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{source2}


\end{document}
```

Any help in this matter would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: It would be better to add a MWE to your question which shows the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\appendix` in report class does not reset the page counter so something else must be doing that. Most likely calling `\pagenumbering` so

```
  \renewcommand\pagenumbering[1]{}
```

would disable that.

Comment: Oh you added a MWE well yes if you are calling `\pagenumbering` explicitly then you can more simply just not do that rather than redefine it to do nothing:-)